# PySpark how to groupby user and sample it in a positive and negative sample rates

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in which the positive and negative rate is less than 1: 100, and I want to random sample it by 1:5 in positive and negative rates for each user.

For example：

```
userid     label    date 
0          1        0708
0          0        0703
1          1        0702
0          0        0701
1          1        0700
1          0        0704
1          0        0705
0          0        0706
1          0        0708
0          0        0710
1          0        0711
0          0        0713
0          0        0714
0          0        0715
0          0        0717
0          0        0718
1          0        0711
1          0        0722
1          0        0715
..., ...
..., ...

# after random sample it in a positive and negative sample rates
userid     label    date 
0          1        0708
0          0        0703
0          0        0701
0          0        0715
0          0        0717
0          0        0718
1          1        0702
1          0        0704
1          0        0705
1          0        0711
1          0        0722
1          0        0715
```

Could anyone help me and give me some hints?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: on what basis did you reject `1          1        0700` over `1          1        0702` ? or is it just random sampling ?

Comment: @Sanket9394 Random sampling. Sry to ignore that before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your starting dataframe is called `df`

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

#Segregate into Positive n negative 
df_0=df.filter(df.label == 0)
df_1=df.filter(df.label == 1)

#Create a window groups together records of same userid with random order
window_random = Window.partitionBy(col('userid')).orderBy(F.rand())

# For Negative Dataframe , rank and choose rank <= 5
data_0 = df_0.withColumn('rank', F.rank().over(window_random)).filter(F.col('rank') <= 5).drop('rank')

# For Positive Dataframe , rank and choose rank <= 1
data_1 = df_1.withColumn('rank', F.rank().over(window_random)).filter(F.col('rank') <= 1).drop('rank')

#Finally union both results 
final_result = data_1.union(data_0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I found your sample too small for the ration provided.I would try SampleBy

#Create fraction column

```
frac = df.select("label").distinct().withColumn("frac", F.when(col('label')=='1',lit(0.1)).otherwise(lit(0.5))).rdd.collectAsMap()
print(frac)
```

#SampleBy

```
 sampled_df = df.sampleBy("label", frac, seed=3)
    sampled_df.show()

+------+-----+----+
|userid|label|date|
+------+-----+----+
|     0|    0| 701|
|     1|    1| 700|
|     1|    0| 704|
|     0|    0| 706|
|     0|    0| 710|
|     1|    0| 711|
|     0|    0| 713|
|     0|    0| 715|
|     0|    0| 718|
|     1|    0| 711|
+------+-----+----+
```